# How to use PowerShell to rename an executable from its details

Tags: windows, batch, powershell, rename

I have lots of `.exe` files and I want to rename them all in one command.

I found the next one but how do I put `ProductName` & `ProductVersion` in next code?

```
(gci).name | Where-Object {$_ -like 'file*.exe'} | foreach { $name=(get-item $_).versioninfo.productname;rename-item $_ -NewName "$name.exe"}
```

Is there another way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make it like ProductName_ProductVersion.exe :

```
(gci -Path "E:\test" -Filter *.exe).FullName | %{$NewName = (Get-Item $_).VersionInfo.ProductName +"_" + (Get-Item $_).VersionInfo.ProductVersion;Rename-Item $_ -NewName "$($NewName).exe"}
```

and if you want to make it like ProductName_FileVersion.exe just replace ProductVersion with FileVersion in code

DO NOT forget to replace `E:\test` with true path